# $\{ \frac{n}{2^k} = x \}$ , A simple Question that's bothering me.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm quite fascinated by the above Simple question. i.e.,

> If I just make $k$ as big as, say $k \ge  10^8 $ , then it's quite heavy to compute the value of $2^k$.
>
> My query is, if that becomes the case, then Given the values of $n$ & $k$, how can we find $x$ alternatively which can be more efficient (efficient in a sense that, the process will be computationally cost effective)?
>
> [ say, either by making the computationally costly operation $(2^k)$ as minimum  as possible or by avoiding it completely ] ?

I'm curious about this.

EDIT $1$ :

> And what if, $n$ is also large? (say, $n \geq 10^{18}$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try logarithm,$$x=\frac{n}{2^k}=\exp(\ln n - k \ln 2) $$

Answer (score 2):

If you want it exactly there is not much to be done.  $2^{10^8}$ has about $30,000,000$ decimal places.  It is easy to compute in binary, if $n$ is supplied that way-just shift the radix point $10^8$ places and you are done.

Unless $n$ is very large, $x$ will be very close to $0$.  Maybe $0$ is a good enough approximation.  You can take logarithms and find $\log x = \log n - k\log 2$.  That will easily give you the magintude of $x$.

Comment: if, $n$ is also large, then? (say, $n \geq 10^{20}$ )

Comment: If $n \approx 10^{20}$ the fraction is still *tiny*.  It will be about $10^{-29999980}$